# Can I upgrade Kubuntu 18.04 to 20.04?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, kubuntu

I can find upgrade instructions for gnome/gtk but there is nothing about how to accomplish using KDE. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  I'd suggest following the [Kubuntu release notes](https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-20-04-lts-has-been-released/) and [Upgrade instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades/Kubuntu)

Command is, if from a GUI terminal (eg. `kconsole`)

```
do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE
```

but please read the release notes and follow the upgrade instructions rather than copy/paste from this answer (*alternatives exist if you prefer all in the konsole; and reminders you should ensure you're fully upgraded etc*).

Comment: After I read the release notes and followed the upgrade instructions it went smoothly.

Comment: You can 'accept' the answer if you're happy. I'll encourage you to always follow the teams own instructions (*release notes* are usually the best place to look, they'll either provide instructions (*like main Ubuntu does*) or have a link to an upgrade link as Kubuntu did).  The team involved will have QA-tested (*Quality Assurance tested*) what is documented.